# How to set item count of list by report parameter value?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I am designing a Telerik Report. I have some static content in a panel which I want to repeat as many times as one of Parameter value. For this I want to use a List. I don't have any data source.

**How can I set the bindings of the list such that it repeats the items as many times as the parameter value?**

N.B: I am using Telerik Report Designer R3 2021 to design the report.